# How to write ajax function in c#

Tags: c#

The Below function how to write in c# backend. The Post Method via to get list.

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetCustomers",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use the asp.net web api 2

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Customer model in backend, then you can try this:

```
    [HttpPost]
     public string GetCustomers()
     {
         List<Customers> listCustomers = new List<Customers>(); 
          /* the list of customers that is returned from the 
            database or from where you are picking the data*/

        CustomersViewModel model = new CustomersViewModel(){
                customers = listCustomers;
            }   

         return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);          
     }
```